# How can I program a unique sort (basically DISTINCT) in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, count, unique

I have an excel program which is a combination of sheet formulas and VBA code that draws from relatively large data (roughly 3.5M cells).  I need to count the number of unique elements of a specific set of data within various combinations of other categories.  I am accomplishing this right now by having the VBA script dump the data onto a live Excel sheet which calculates the unique and then moving the count to a hard cell.  This process is taking 20 minutes to run and I am certain that it would improve by counting the unique identifiers within the VBA script (I could also then shut off the formula calculation while it runs, etc.).  A simplified example:

1 yellow John/
2 green  John/
1 red    Mack/
5 green  Cindy/
4 blue   Lou

I need to count the number of Lou's within each number-color combination, the number of greens within each number-name combination, and the number of 2's within each color-name combination.

The sort on the sheet works like this:
A2 starts with a 1 and then the rest of A uses:
=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:$B3,B3)=1,A2+1,A2) (and dragged down)

Column B holds the data.  Column C uses:
     =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW()-1,$A$2:$B$1953,2,FALSE),"") (all cells in this column are the same formula)

Comment: This sounds like a query table could solve this.  Query your source data, group the elements in question.  Start here but use an excel source instead.  Its pretty quick once set up, just some investment in understwnding the method required.  I use this all the time. http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/microsoft-query.html

Comment: Are you suggesting that I query the data within the same Excel file?  I expect that you are not, in which case querying the source data is not an option (that would make life so much easier-I love SQL!).  It is a long story which involves too many pieces of software, international data, etc.

Comment: No am not, I believe there are memory leek issues doing that. If appropriate once you've brought all your data together treat it as a master file.